# mediaelement.js: SD HD buttons and no-scale in full screen / window

Tags: mediaelement.js

Two questions: Is it possible to add SD and HD (standard and high definition) buttons to the mediaelement player to the same end effect as YouTube or Vimeo so the user can switch between them within the player?

Does mediaelement support full screen (or full window either is fine) without scaling the video to fill? Vimeo does this with a "no scale" button in full screen but YouTube does not, YouTube always stretches the video to fill the screen.

I'm not a developer, so forgive the question if the answer appears obvious.

Comment: have you got something for this issue, i also need to add HD/SD button